# useEffect infinite loop when updating state and including dependency array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I always find this a bit weird with React that it is said to be an anti-pattern to not add all dependencies to the `useEffect` hook and warnings are shown in the console.

Take this example. I am using `swr` and `useSWRInfinite` - see [example](https://swr.vercel.app/examples/infinite-loading) here and docs [here](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/pagination#useswrinfinite).

My code looks checks that a element is `inView` and if so it fetches the next page of data.

This all works fine

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (inView) {
      setSize(size + 1)
    }
}, [inView, setSize])
```

but if I add `size` to the dependency array an infinite loop occurs as I am updating the `size` within `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (inView) {
    setSize(size + 1)
  }
}, [inView, setSize, size]) <------ everything breaks
```

Can anyone advise on the correct way of handling this. After reading through many SO answers and blog posts nothing is any clearer.

Comment: don't put `setSize` in the dependency array. it's already guaranteed to be constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have added `size` in the dependency array. So, the `useEffect` will run whenever `size` changes. Now, in your `useEffect`, you are incrementing `size` using the `setSize` setter. This will again cause `size` to change and again run the `useEffect`.

If you want to refer to the previous `size`, you can use the callback version of the `setSize`.

```
setSize((previousSize) => previousSize + 1)
```

This way, your linter won't complain when you don't add `size` in the dependency array because now you are not using it.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't supposed to use the size state inside the setSize.
You can change it to
`setSize(size => size + 1)`
And then remove the size from the dependency array.
Can read more here: [enter link description here](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state)